# Why Azure App service IP address not the in the integrated VNet IP address range?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I do not have networking background. I hope someone can explain to me about the Azure App service IP address. I have App Services which are integrated with my Azure VNet. But the inbound/outbound IP Addresses of those App Services are not in the range of VNet IP addresses. Why? What's the purpose of VNet integration?

In a on-premise network, if your service is running on a server in a subnet, the IP address of the service is normally the IP address of the server. Why it is so different on Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VNet integration is meant to allow **outbound** traffic from your App Service app to be pushed into a private VNet rather than go directly to the public internet. It is **not** meant to grant inbound private access / deploy your App Service within the VNet.

If you want to isolate your App Service, then you should have a look to [Azure Service Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/overview) that allows you to deploy your App inside a VNet. Then, the IP of your App Service will be in sync with the IP range of your VNet.